# Overlay is mixed with the footer

Tags: bug

This happened to me couple of minutes ago. I wanted to save edit, but this happened.

Please note how the "How to Format" interacts with the background.
I am using Chrome on Mac Sierra.
[image]

The question has been marked as a duplicate, but in my opinion it is not. They way "How to Format" dialogue is bugged on my example is different then on the suggested duplicate.

Comment: The side bar is so important,  it's always on top.. _Sometimes_.

Comment: Not dupe as every dupe linked to this dupe speak about "How to format overlaps" when here you can notice that it's not a 100% overlap cause footer link overlaps back the overlaping" how to format".

Comment: But I guess with not Red hand circle those detail can not catch your attention/